# Set row2 value to same as row1 value whose column as same

Tags: mysql

I have one table that looks like below image :

[image]

Here I have marked two row. There are two different meta keys one is **_regular_price** and another is **_price**.

Now I want to update **meta_value** of **_price** meta_key and set price as the **_regular_price**.

So what query should I have to  write?

Answer (score 1):

You can use self-join:

```
update yourtable t1
join yourtable t2
on t1.post_id = t2.post_id and t2.meta_key = '_regular_price'
set t1.meta_value = t2.meta_value 
where t1.meta_key = '_price'
```

Answer (score 0):

do it this way:

```
update table1 set meta_key= '_regular_price' where meta_id = 2364389
```

hope it helps.